# UIDatePicker minimum date with no sunday

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

How to set the minimum date of an UIDatePicker to today + 5days with no Sunday included in the 5 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below first checks for the current weekday (Gregorian calendar => Sunday=1). If today is a day after Tuesday, then there will be a Sunday in today+5 days (see calculation of the `offset`).
After calculating the offset, it will be added to the current date.

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
int offset = (components.weekday >= 3) ? 6 : 5;
NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit value:offset toDate:currentDate options:0];

//datePicker.minimumDate = minDate;
```

Comment: Was about to post a very similar answer, but I believe it should be components.weekday >= 3 since 3 == Tuesday

Comment: This line NSDate *minDate = [gregorian dateByAddingUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit value:offset toDate:currentDate options:0]; is only available for iOS8. What about iOS 7?

Comment: For iOS7, you may use `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`